# Getting Static Map From Google Maps - Do I have a memory leak?

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks, bitmap, eclipse-memory-analyzer

This is my first Android application and its going good but I've started to get GC_CONCURRENT messages in my LogCat.  I've read that this is the Garbage Collector and its seems to free up about %6-%7 every time reported in log cat(4-5 times it seems). Now I'm not sure if this means I have a leak or not?

I installed the MAT plugin and this is what it showed me:

[http://imageshack.us/a/img694/5589/suspectandroid.png http://imageshack.us/a/img694/5589/suspectandroid.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img694/5589/suspectandroid.png)

[http://imageshack.us/a/img820/4295/domtreeandroid.png http://imageshack.us/a/img820/4295/domtreeandroid.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img820/4295/domtreeandroid.png)

It seems to show that I'm taking up over %60 of the memory with Bitmap related things?

Here is my code to get the Bitmap:

```
public void LoadMap()
{
    Thread web = new Thread() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {

            try 
            { 
                Location loc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                String mapURL = MAP_URL + "center=" + loc.getLatitude() + "," + loc.getLongitude() +"&zoom=" + MAP_ZOOM + "&size=" + MAP_SIZE + "&maptype=" + MAP_TYPE + "&sensor=true";

                map = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(mapURL).getContent());

                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.what = 1;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            } catch (Exception e) { Log.i("ERROR:", "" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }; web.start();

}

private Handler handler = new Handler()  
{
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
  {
    switch(msg.what)
    {
    case 1:
        SetMap();
        break;
    }
  }
};

public void SetMap()
    {    
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(map);
    }
```

Now it gives me a warning that the handler should be static to prevent potential memory leaks, but I'm not sure if that is whats affecting me? Or how to update my UI once the map has been loaded from the server.

Comment: You don't have a leak there. The resource object is representing all the resource images / drawables from your `/res` folder. They are always there. The Handler warning is about the fact that Handler that have messages enqueued prevent your `Activity` from being garbage collected because they have an implicit reference to the outer `this` which is probably not a big problem for you.

Comment: So I shouldn't need to worry about this much?  Thanks for replying.